# Is it possible to train a model on StanfordNLP for Python and use it in the Java-based CoreNLP?

Tags: java, python, nlp, stanford-nlp

StanfordNLP has two main libraries: one for Java and another for Python. For Java, it contains the [CoreNLP package](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). However, I have a dependency parsing model trained in the Python's version of the [Stanfordnlp library](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/index.html).

My main question: is it possible to load the Python's trained package using CoreNLP?

I checked their documentations and tutorials and found nothing on the compatibility between the two libraries. I know that Python's training is done through neural networks, and although the Java version doesn't necessarily use NNs, StanfordNLP does have a [Neural Network implementation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.html) for Java. This led me to believe that there could be some way for me to load the Python's model on Java. By the way, the extension of the files are different, Python version outputs a .dt file and for java a .gz is used. I thought about compression the .dt file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: One of possible option is   A) Deploy your Python's trained model as REST API service using Flask and Flask-restful  and B) Call deployed model APIs in Java as REST API calls

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kaa, this is actually how it is implemented nowadays. But I'd like to load it together with the remaining models. The reason is, we have a pipeline for many languages on Java, and I'd like to add a new dependency tree for a new language that I trained on Python's StanfordNLP. It is faster to have everything under the same framework with requiring REST API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jython to train a model in python and load in Java for Stanford coreNLP.

Comment: can you elaborate on it, please? Is there a tutorial or example I can look further on it?